# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': when adding options to select

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

I am trying to dynamically add options to my select form. I would like the different options listed to be the names found within the products array. I keep getting an error saying "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'". Shouldn't `.innerText` let me directly place these names within each option?

```js
class Product {
  constructor(name, price, category) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.category = category
  }
}

const product1 = new Product('Apple', '$1.99', 'Fruit');
const product2 = new Product('Lettuce', '$3.99', 'Vegetable');
const product3 = new Product('Avocado', '$2.99', 'Fruit');

let products = [product1, product2, product3];
console.log(products)

function postOrder() {
  const customerName = document.getElementById('customerName').value
  const address = document.getElementById('customerAddress').value
  const card = document.getElementById('creditCard').value
  const select = document.getElementById('orderSelect');
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement('option').innerText = products[i].name;
    select.appendChild(option)
  }
}
postOrder()
```

```html
<h1>Add Order:</h1>
<form id='orderForm'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Customer Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerAddress" placeholder="Address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="card">Customer Credit Card:</label>
    <input type="Number" class="form-control" id="creditCard" placeholder='Credit Card Number'>
  </div>
  <select id='orderSelect' class="form-select" aria-label="Default">

  </select>
  <div class='form-select'>
    <button type="button" id="orderBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add Order</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
    let option = document.createElement('option').innerText = products[i].name;
```

sets both `innerText` and `option` to `products[i].name`. You need to split it up so you set `option` to the new element, and then set its `innerText`.

```
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerText = products[i].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
let option = document.createElement('option').innerText = products[i].name;
```

Returns the text that was assigned, not the element. It should be:

```
let option = document.createElement('option');
option.innerText = products[i].name;
```

You can do `let option = new Option(products[i].name);` as a single line alternative.

```js
class Product {
  constructor(name, price, category) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.category = category
  }
}

const product1 = new Product('Apple', '$1.99', 'Fruit');
const product2 = new Product('Lettuce', '$3.99', 'Vegetable');
const product3 = new Product('Avocado', '$2.99', 'Fruit');

let products = [product1, product2, product3];
//console.log(products)

function postOrder() {
  const customerName = document.getElementById('customerName').value
  const address = document.getElementById('customerAddress').value
  const card = document.getElementById('creditCard').value
  const select = document.getElementById('orderSelect');
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    let option = new Option(products[i].name);
    select.appendChild(option)
  }
}

postOrder()
```

```html
<h1>Add Order:</h1>
<form id='orderForm'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Customer Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerAddress" placeholder="Address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="card">Customer Credit Card:</label>
    <input type="Number" class="form-control" id="creditCard" placeholder='Credit Card Number'>
  </div>
  <select id='orderSelect' class="form-select" aria-label="Default">




  </select>
  <div class='form-select'>
    <button type="button" id="orderBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add Order</button>
  </div>
</form>
```